# Windows applications resized incorrectly when moving between monitors with different resolutions and scaling

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, windows-10-v1703, 4k-resolution, high-dpi

I have a new laptop that has a 4K display.  It's set at the recommended 250% zoom level.  I also have 2 Full HD monitors plugged into it (1920x1080) each set at the recommended zoom level of 100%.  The 4K display is in the middle with Full HD monitor on each side.

The issue I'm having is moving an application from the Full HD screen to the 4K display and vice versa.  When using the Windows-Shift Right/Left keys to move between screens, the application usually gets resized incorrectly where it ends up being too small or too large (exceeding the screen) and I need to manually resize it.  A similar problem happens if I drag an application from the 4K to the Full HD screen and vice versa.  It's become a hassle to have to manually resize the applications after they are moved to a different display.

**Does anyone have any tips on how to make the applications resize accurately when moving them to a different resolution/zoom level monitor?**  I'd consider a 3rd party application if Windows itself is unable to do it.  I'm on Windows 10 Creators Update.

## Examples

Below shows what happens when I move Chrome, the MS Calculator app and File Explorer from one screen to the next using the Windows-Shift Left/Right keyboard shortcuts.

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome Step 1]

(Chrome didn't move over completely to the middle screen - it's on both screens)
[image: Chrome Step 2]

**Calculator App**
[image: Calculator App Step 1]

(a little too small when moved to the 4K display, could be larger)
[image: Calculator App Step 2]

(now moving back to the Full HD screen, it's gigantic and off the screen)
[image: Calculator App Step 3]

**File Explorer**
[image: File Explorer Step 1]

(same as Chrome, moving to the 4K screen, it's on 2 screens)
[image: File Explorer Step 2]

(moving back to the Full HD screen, it's very small.  If I continue to move back to the 4K screen and then back to the Full HD screen, it gets even smaller)
[image: File Explorer Step 3]

Comment: Microsoft adds improvements to DPI scaling in 1703. is this your own (self coded) application or a 3rd party tool that causes the issues?

Comment: I'm on version 1703.  These are not my applications.  Examples are Chrome, the MS Calculator app and even File Explorer.  With File Explorer, the window can get really small when there is plenty of room and no need for it to shrink down.  Then I'm stuck needing to manually enlarge it.

Comment: I've added some screenshots showing what happens when trying to move the apps from screen to screen using the built-in Windows keyboard shortcuts... Windows-Shift Left/Right.

Comment: You should try the settings explained in this page [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/175664/how-to-make-the-windows-desktop-work-well-on-high-dpi-displays-and-fix-blurry-fonts/)

Comment: Thanks @spike_66 that is quite useful.  It doesn't address the specific issue I'm having of having the windows resize correctly when moving an application from one screen to the next (in particular with the Windows-Shift Right/Left keyboard shortcuts).  I'm looking for an efficient and accurate way to do that.  (that link does have some good tips on dealing with blurriness which was the first issue I had before coming onto this window resizing issue I'm asking about here)

Comment: ask Google to update Chrome. application developers need to add the functionality. store apps like calculator are DPI compatible by default

Comment: The DPI and quality seems to be okay on all the apps (Chrome, Calculator, File Explorer etc).  To clarify the problem is when moving the apps from screen to screen in particular with the shortcut key Windows-Shift Left/Right, the application either doesn't move over completely to the next screen or it moves to the next screen but is resized poorly ... either too small or too large.  See my screenshot examples of the Calculator app, it got super enlarged and the bottom half is off the screen.

Comment: I've started trialling a 3rd party app, DisplayFusion, which is getting the job done.  It has its own keyboard shortcuts to "Move Window to Next Monitor and Size Proportionally" which is correctly resizing the apps when I move them from the 4K Display to 1080p (Full HD) screens.  Looks like there's at least one other 3rd party software that may do this too, but going to stick with DisplayFusion for now.

Comment: For me this has finally started working correctly with the 1809 Windows 10 update.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Now it's really simple to solve.
My monitor (2) 24 inch has resolution 1920 x 1080 and my laptop (1) 17 inch has resolution 3840 x 2160. With a zoom factor of 250%.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now reduce the resolution of your laptop to match your monitor.

[image]

[image]

Or even lower because my laptop has a smaller monitor.

[image]

[image]

Set the scaling to 100% (This makes the dialog change in size when moving from one to the other monitor.)

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the only working solution

Comment: worked for me as well

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with -among other programs- Google Chrome. Really a hazzle.
This was the solution for me:
Right-click on the program shortcut.
Click "Properties".
Choose the tab: "Compatibility".
Chose Edit compatibility for high dpi.
Check Override high DPI scaling behavior. Choose Scaling performed by System.

Answer (score 1):

Does your laptop have an NVidia graphics adapter?

I use DSR (Dynamic super resolution) to fix a similar issue on my desktop.

I have 2 4k displays and a 1080p display, and by enabling DSR on the 1080p screen I can set all of them to be reported at 4k.

DSR can be enabled in the Nvidia control panel under "manage 3d settings", and then the increased resolution can be set in the normal windows resolution dialog.

Comment: Thanks @eldorel, I do have an NVidia graphics adapter but don't appear to have the DSR feature (I checked in Manage 3D Settings and updated my driver).  I have an NVIDIA Quadro M1000M.  Your solution sounds good though.  So far I've gotten by with the DisplayFusion 3rd party software as noted in my comments above (the free version).

Answer (score 1):

I have a lame workaround - still seeking a solution.  When you drag the window from the 4K resolution monitor to the HD monitor, it will automatically resize if the entire app fits the HD screen vertically. That means that if you shrink the height by 2.5x before dragging it, the app will resize to a readable resolution on the 4K monitor.  The application window is now 2.5x too small, but fits the monitor, so it can be easily resized to a comfortable size.  It a bit annoying, but with practice.... nah, let's face it - The only real solution is to upgrade your monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue with my recent build. I have one 28" 4K monitor and two 21" HD monitors. Windows scaling is working "fine" but the annoying thing is when I drag a window across monitors (from 4K to HD). It is driving me CRAZY.

The "solution" for me was to set both 21" to 4K. Windows are no longer resized when moved across displays, but everything is blurry. It's also annoying, but you know, less so !!!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with my dual 4K and HD monitors. This is an old post but still posting a solution, might help someone.

Github: https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse
Download (Releases): https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse/releases

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with an LG 4k monitor, I solved the problem by installing the drives provided by LG (https://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers?customerModelCode=43UN700-B&csSalesCode=43UN700-B.AUS&category=CT10000030&subcategory=OTHERS#modal_window_drivers).

At this point the problem is drives provided by Windows

Answer (score 0):

HOW I SOLVED THIS: Your 4K monitor has a ratio of 2160/3840 = 0.5625
Adjust the other monitors to the same ratio (0.5625) by choosing one of the available resolutions.
Then, make sure you have the same "Scale and Layout" magnification in all three monitors (if you have 150% in your 4K monitor, make it 150% on the other monitors too).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the 4k of the 4k monitor, and if you have Nvidia Graphics, in the Nvidia control panel create a custom resolution for your 1080p monitor and make it 3840x2160. Then adjust scaling as necessary. However, this may make your 1080p monitor a little blurry, but its a worthy sacrifice.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 includes a convenient keyboard shortcut that can instantly move a window to another display without the need for a mouse.

If you want to move a window to a display located to the left of your current display, press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>.
If you want to move a window to a display located to the right of your current display, press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>.